# Getter that loops through the variables of a struct

Tags: c++, loops, struct

There's a small program that has various options, and these need some input values -- they are in a `struct`. Each option requires an instance of the `struct`, so there's an `array` of `struct`. I would like to be able to save these options at program exit and read them at program start. But the `struct` doesn't hold only 3 variables, and they may grow in time as my small program grows. An example of the `struct`:

```
struct S
{
    int a;
    float b;
    std::vector<float> c;
}
```

The save file has as many rows as there are options, and each row contins the same sequence, but different values, which are separated by `;`, the elements of the vectors with `,` and a terminating `;`, no spaces. For the above example:

```
13;3.14;0.618,1.618;
7;2.718;12.3,45.6;
...
```

But the file can get corrupt, so reading it corrupts the variables and the program crashes. Currently, reading the numbers involves a loop (the number of options/rows is known):

```
float x;
char c;
std::fstream fs;
// file open, flags, etc
fs >> a >> c;
if(c != ';')
{
    std::cerr << "Error! ...\n";
    break;
}
fs >> b >> c;
if(c != ';')
{
    std::cerr << "Error! ...\n";
    break;
}
c = ',';  // make sure c is not ';'
while(c != ';')
{
    fs >> x >> c;
    c.push_back(x);
    if(c != ',')
    {
        std::err << "Error...\n";
        break;
    }
}
```

Instead of `break` it can be an `abort()` function, or one that starts from scratch, not the problem, but if there are 100 variables, I have to do this for everyone. That's why I was thinking of looping through them. Apparently there's no "reflection" in C++, but it could be done via some macros. Currently, I don't understand either of them, so I tried my own solution. First, I tried making a general `use()` function with a template, but it fails when called, with `template argument deduction/substitution failed`. I tried `auto` as the type, but also fails. I suppose it makes sense. So then I thought why not just make a `set/get` that handles the worst possible type and converts it, internally. This is what member functions came up:

```
enum { INT_A, FLOAT_B, VECTOR_C, ALL };
void set(const int &n, const float &f, const int &i = 0)
{
    switch(n)
    {
        case INT_A:     a = static_cast<int>(x);  break;
        case FLOAT_B:   b = x;                    break;
        case VECTOR_C:  c[i] = x;                 break;
    }
}
float get(const int &n, const int &i = 0)
{
    switch(n)
    {
        case INT_A:     return static_cast<float>(a); break;
        case FLOAT_B:   return b;                     break;
        case VECTOR_C:  return c[i];                  break;
    }
}
```

`get()` is mostly for confirming, `set()` is what interests me. It does seem to work, I can set up a loop to iterate and automate the process, but is this a good solution (I somehow doubt it is, but I am not advanced)? Are there better ones that do not involve external libraries?

---

Sorry for the delay, I simply forgot to update it. I decided to use an additional `std::vector<float>` that holds all the variables as `float`. The order is that the original `std::vector<float>` (`c` in the above example) are all, sequentially, last in the vector. The downside is that it occupies about twice as much memory, but less code. Now, I know that the vector `c` (and the rest in the real case scenario) have a minimum length, so I have two options:

1. impose the length if the additional vector to include these minimum lengths, then, when it's about writing, I need an `if()` deciding whether I need to write *until* the minimum length, or *above* it, something like this:

   if(c.size() < minLength)
       // loop to write to c[i]
   else
       // loop to c.push_back(...)
2. or I could just consider the length of the additional vector made of the number of single variables, like `a` and `b`, and considering the length of the `vector` (`c`) zero, thus, when writing, the code will reduce to a `for()` or `while()` loop with `push_back()`.

I opted for the second, so the `struct` now looks like this:

```
struct S
{
    int a;
    float b;
    std::vector<float> c;
    std::vector<float> additional(2);  // holds a and b, c islength zero
}
```

The writing to vector can be easily implemented in a loop. A quick show looks like this:

```
int n;
float x;
char c;
while(n < maxSizeOfAdditional)
{
    switch(n)
    {
        case 1:  a = static_cast<int>(additional[i]);  break;
        case 2:  b = additional[i];                    break;
        case 3:
        {
            while(fs >> x >> c)
                // loop for writing c.push_back(x)
        }
    }
    ++n;
}
```

I need the original types because of the rest of the code in the program, thus the need for `static_cast`. It works now, and there is no "reflection", nor did I need one, I just needed *a way* to automate the process with a loop.

Still, I don't know if it's an "orthodox" approach. For my part, it seems to have solved my problem, but I don't know how something like this would be considered. Better yet, I don't know how "the usual" way is done with programs that need to read/write variables to savefiles, variables that must reside somewhere (I just imagined them in a `struct`, that's all). I suppose time will tell.

Comment: Why do you want to loop over members? What is your use case for the feature?

Comment: @Incomputable Around the middle of the post I am saying why.

Comment: @aconcernedcitizen Indeed. Chances are you want to rethink the approach. C++ is doing just fine without the reflection.

Comment: @aconcernedcitizen, can you somehow reorder contents of the post so the actual problem comes first and your approach/trials are next to it?

Comment: @Incomputable Alright, I'll try it now.

Comment: @aconcernedcitizen, as for your problem, perhaps overloading `operator>>` might work for you? I recommend reading about overloading stream operator in C++

Comment: I have a hard time seeing how `set(INT_A, value)` is an improvement over `set_a(value)`. Writing 3 setters would require about 6 lines of code, now you already have 10...

Comment: @BoPersson With the first version, I can use it in a loop, based on the `enum` in the `struct`. That loop can also take care of the `if(c != ';')`. With the second, I need to explicitly write all of them, and I have, again, the same situation as with the `if(c != 'c')`, which is what I would ilke to avoid.

Comment: @Ron I didn't say I want to implement reflection, I just want a way to iterate through the variables, conveniently, without explicitly getting one by one and making checks at each step. I came up with this solution, but I have no idea if it's a vlaid one, or acceptable.

Comment: @Incomputable I am sorry, while I know about overloading, I don't see how that will ease up the checking at each step. No doubt it's something very simple that I don't see.

Comment: @aconcernedcitizen, streams are convertible to `bool`, which says if the last I/O was successful. You can then use `while (stream >> object) {your code here}` to read until error or stream is exhausted.

Comment: @Incomputable I remember having it written like that, in some past attemps, but I had to do it with `while(fs >> x >> c)` and then check for `c`, but that seemd to be about the same thing as it is now. There was also a `while(fs >> c)` but that required some extra `atoi()` or `atof()`, so I just wrote it as it is now. Besides, this would only work in the case of the `vector`, for the other variables, I can't automate the process unless I loop through them. Hence, my attempt at solving.

Comment: A possible soln could be using `reinterpret_cast` in c++, by-which you can first cast to int and from second variable of struct until the end interpret again `float` and iterate through pointer increment. However I personally didn't use/ try it.

Comment: @JeJo, that will make code non-portable and getting into undefined behavior will be much more likely.

Comment: At the very least, if there is no other method, is what I have done "orthodox" enough? I mean using `static_cast` like that to have only one function that allows me to loop through the variables? It may not win the Oscar for programming, but, as long as it gets the job done... I'll have to keep it until something comes up.

Comment: @aconcernedcitizen, you need to put ping mark `@` and username to notify about reply. Passing by reference business will not end well for non-default constructible objects. I'm still not entirely sure what your problem is. If you have 100 named variables in one class/struct, then there is a problem. Try to group them into arrays/`std::vector`s or something.

Comment: @Incomputable I'll return brute type if I have to, but the problem is that it's a soup of types, it's... Actually, what if I use them all as `floats`? Then I can make it a `vector`. After all, I have checks futher down in the program that don't allow entering unwanted numbers. I suppose it would be a bit of a waste in memory, but only a few are `unsigned char` and `short`, two or three `bool`, in rest it's `float` and `vector<float>`. You just might have given the solution ...so far, at least. I'll wait some more, maybe there will be someone else to suggest something. If not, make it answer.

Comment: Tangential: use `do`-`while` rather than faking the first test.

Comment: @DavisHerring Are you referring to the piece of code that starts with `float x`? If yes, that is inside a `while()` loop: "Currently, reading the numbers involves a loop".

Comment: @aconcernedcitizen: I meant the `c=',';` used to disable the first `c!=';'` test.